# Can I stick a php readdir script in a Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I would like to stick a php code (readdir and print links to page) into a Dynamic Ajax Content script like below. Is this even possible as I am getting errors? Any help would be very appreciated.

```
<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('PHP_SCRIPT_HERE', 'rightcolumn');">TEXT HERE DOES NOT MATTER</a>
```

This is the PHP script I want to use to scan the directory and print links to page.

```
         <?php

// These files will be ignored
$excludedFiles = array (
'excludeMe.file',
'excludeMeAs.well'
 );

  // These file extensions will be ignored
   $excludedExtensions = array (
    'html',
    'xslt',
     'htm',
 );

 // Make sure we ignore . and ..
 $excludedFiles = array_merge($excludedFiles,array('.','..')); 

 // Convert to lower case so we are not case-sensitive
 for ($i = 0; isset($excludedFiles[$i]); $i++) $excludedFiles[$i] =   
strtolower(ltrim($excludedFiles[$i],'.'));
for ($i = 0; isset($excludedExtensions[$i]); $i++) $excludedExtensions[$i] =   
strtolower($excludedExtensions[$i]);

// Loop through directory
$dir = 'dir_1/dir_2/';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {

while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  $extn = explode('.',$file);
  $extn = array_pop($extn);
  // Only echo links for files that don't match our rules
  if (!in_array(strtolower($file),$excludedFiles) &&    
  !in_array(strtolower($extn),$excludedExtensions)) {
    $count++;
    print("<a href=\"".$dir.$file."\">".$file."</a><br />\n");
  }
 }
 echo '<br />';
 closedir($handle);
 }

?>
```

Comment: _What_ errors are you getting? Are they PHP errors or JavaScript errors?

Comment: The error that I get is that the page opens but in a new browser page. I want to use the javascript as like an ajax version of an iframe with out having to reload the page and do a http request.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing a html element with the id of rightcolumn?

You need to add a div or some other container on the page with the id of rightcolumn. The script will then populate this container with the output of your php script.

Comment: I have done that here: 
<div id="rightcolumn"><h3>Choose a page to load.</h3></div>
<div style="clear: left; margin-bottom: 1em"></div>

</body>